# Create a proxy between the client and a DB to minimize the risk

Tags: c#, database, security

I am creating a simple desktop application that allows multiple users to work on the database in the special GUI (details are not important). However, there is a security risk that a user might misuse the credentials (connection string etc. in the program) if extracted, connect and e.g. delete all data in the tables he is allowed to access. I want to address this risk so I think I should use a proxy? The client will communicate to the proxy and the proxy would be performing only allowed queries. However I think it will be really difficult to implement a server - client solution like that, with all the data transfer from proxy to client. Or is there any other solution to address this issue?

Comment: Why not use a connection string with username that has a read-only privileges?

Comment: Well the user should e.g. add/modify only his records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of thinking to create server proxy is fine, but creating server as standalone application will be pain. Especially if you must handle serialization/deserialization to send data between client and proxy.
So you may be insterested in WCF DataContracts, and when you map your database on server side to any ORM you can comminicate between client and WCF using class representing your data. And you can make authentication just between client and WCF. In this way client will be separated from database and implementation of this solution isn't painful.